# Comparing two Pandas dataframes row by row and inserting matching value into the other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas DataFrames named complete_data and raw_data. My intention is to look up the date column (row by row) of raw_data DataFrames in the complete_data DataFrames. For the rows of raw_data DataFrames found in the complete_data, I want to insert the corresponding row in P1 and P2 into complete_data.

Please note:

1. The unique key in both DataFrames is the 'date' and the complete_data DataFrame has the complete set of 'dates' that need other columns to be fetched from raw_data DataFrame.
2. I want the final Dataframe to be the 'complete_data' DataFrame having NaN values where date does not exists in the raw_data DataFrame. And where 'date' exists, the rows in columns P1 and P2 be inserted into complete_data DataFrame.

Here is my sample of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
complete_data = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2010-01-01','2010-01-02','2010-01-03','2010-01-04','2010-01-05','2010-01-06','2010-01-07','2010-01-08']})

raw_data  = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2010-01-01','2010-01-02','2010-01-03','2010-01-05','2010-01-07','2010-01-08'],
                          'P1':['4.4','5.2','5.6','6.2','6.5','7.2'],
                          'P2':['200','220','230','250','270','280']})

column_labels = list(raw_data.columns)
column_labels = column_labels[1:]
complete_data[column_labels] = np.nan

i = 0
while i<raw_data.shape[0]:
    if raw_data['date'].iloc[i] in complete_data['date'].iloc[i]:
        complete_data.iloc[[i],[1,2]]=raw_data.iloc[[i],[1,2]]
    else:
        complete_data.iloc[[i],[1,2]] = raw_data.iloc[[i],[1,2]]
    i+=1
```

**My output is:**

```
         date   P1   P2
0  2010-01-01  4.4  200
1  2010-01-02  5.2  220
2  2010-01-03  5.6  230
3  2010-01-04  6.2  250
4  2010-01-05  6.5  270
5  2010-01-06  7.2  280
6  2010-01-07  NaN  NaN
7  2010-01-08  NaN  NaN
```

**My expected output should be:**

```
         date   P1   P2
0  2010-01-01  4.4  200
1  2010-01-02  5.2  220
2  2010-01-03  5.6  230
3  2010-01-04  NaN  NaN
4  2010-01-05  6.2  250
5  2010-01-06  6.5  270
6  2010-01-07  NaN  NaN
7  2010-01-08  7.2  280
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

For the df:s you gave:

```
 date   P1   P2
0  2010-01-01  4.4  200
1  2010-01-02  5.2  220
2  2010-01-03  5.6  230
3  2010-01-05  6.2  250
4  2010-01-07  6.5  270
5  2010-01-08  7.2  280
```

and

```
  date  P1  P2
0  2010-01-01 NaN NaN
1  2010-01-02 NaN NaN
2  2010-01-03 NaN NaN
3  2010-01-04 NaN NaN
4  2010-01-05 NaN NaN
5  2010-01-06 NaN NaN
6  2010-01-07 NaN NaN
7  2010-01-08 NaN NaN
```

```
df = complete_data.merge(raw_data, on =['date'], how='left').dropna(axis=1, how='all')
df = df.rename(columns={'P1_y':'P1','P2_y':'P2'})
```

which gives:

```
date   P1   P2
0  2010-01-01  4.4  200
1  2010-01-02  5.2  220
2  2010-01-03  5.6  230
3  2010-01-04  NaN  NaN
4  2010-01-05  6.2  250
5  2010-01-06  NaN  NaN
6  2010-01-07  6.5  270
7  2010-01-08  7.2  280
```

Note that the expected output in your question does not match the definition of the dataframes you gave.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt response. I am very grateful. Your comment on my expected output is correct.

Comment: Remember to mark the question as accepted if it fits what you expected. This way it'll disappear from unanswered questions.